# interactive graphic in R

Tags: r, plotly

I produce interactive graphs using plotly  and I can view them in the viewer window in R studio but
how to save this interactive graphic or how to set it in a word document without lost interactivity?
(Not html)
https://rpubs.com/Breshanaj/1155739

I tried this:

```
# Save as .png

library(webshot)
webshot::install_phantomjs()
webshot("https://rpubs.com/Breshanaj/1155739" , "output.png", delay = 0.2 )
```

but it doesn't function.